# Is it possible to run the output itself with pipe '|'? If not, why is so?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

For example:

```
echo "apt install nginx" | <'apt install nginx' will run here>
```

I tried enough searching but couldn't find the answer :(

Comment: `$(echo apt install nginx)`

Comment: Why so? Why should it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user is already aware of the obvious answer (piping to e.g. `sh`) but does not explain why that is not an adequate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
echo "apt install nginx" | sh
```

Comment: in this case unless run as root probably `sudo sh`  ;-)

Comment: @SparedWhisle Actually I know this trick and I did the same for a purpose, but I was just curious if it is possible to just run the command `echo "apt install nginx" |` or if it's not possible why is so?

Comment: then why don't you exactly ask this?

Comment: a pipe connects 2 processes. There has to be a process on the right side.

Comment: @RafafTahsin `Actually I know this trick` – Then you should have stated in the question you know the trick; and you should have explained why it doesn't fit your needs.